# Icon in a GtkStackSidebar

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

Is possible add a icon in the navigation items of `GtkStackSidebar` like the simulation image below?

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this will work, or what minimum version of GTK+ you need for this, but investigate the [`icon-name` child property of GtkStack](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html#GtkStack--c-icon-name). I also don't know if this will let you use custom icons or not.

Comment: It seems to work with `GtkStackSwitcher` [(case)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662257/how-do-i-change-the-property-of-a-gtk-widget-such-as-a-stack).
But according to my tests does not work with `GtkStackSidebar` :(.
I'm setting the property but nothing happened.

Comment: The side bar is just a listbox with labels, you could either make your own with icons or figure out a way to modify it. An example would be Nautilus has a sidebar with icons.

Comment: The Nuatilus sidebar is a `GtkPlacesSidebar`.

Comment: Which is just a listbox as I said.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Gnome Settings use a `GtkListBox`: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-control-center/blob/master/shell/cc-panel-list.ui

Comment: Gnome Tweaks (which is shown in the question) also uses a `ListBox`: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/blob/9b246fef298bff1dceffcf81160d6da652735208/gtweak/tweakview.py#L13 I think that's the best bet.