# How to use images in GTK Stack Switcher

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm writing an application using C++ and gtkmm. I made a Gtk stack in it. Now I want to add images instead of text on stackswitcher's buttons. I assume that it's possible because something like this is made in gtk3-demo:

[image]

Unfortunatelly the example is made using UI file and I want to do it without UI designer. For now I found [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662257/how-do-i-change-the-property-of-a-gtk-widget-such-as-a-stack)

But it's not very helpful to me. The answer was to use `stack.child_set_property` but I checked gtkmm documentation for stack and there isn't anything like this for C++. The closest match was `Gtk::Stack::child_property_name` with adnotation that it returns `A ChildPropertyProxy that allows you to get or set the value of the property, or receive notification when the value of the property changes`. I suppose this may be the thing i'm looking for, but due to lack of examples I have no idea how to use it.

To sum up: Is anyone able to tell me how to set an image as StackSwitcher's label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems I've found an answer. I'll post it if anyone needs it in the future:
To change Stack Switcher's text label into image I just needed to do that:

```
stack->child_property_icon_name(ChildName) = "Icon Name";
```

Comment: That's the spirit, don't be afraid of accepting your own answer, too. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Hello :) I'll accept it, but i can accept my own answer in 2 days